Webserver changing from root to User - How can do it?
At my beginning i installed Mautic and the webserver Apache2 under root.
Now i know, that was wrong and i added a user: stefan
What do i have to do, that the apache and my mautic webapp is runnung under the user stefan instead of root?

I would let that go. Use apache as the apache user. That is the default. Using default means less alterations so less timeconsuming

hmmm....i'm not a professional at this - i need here more explaining for that issue:
I installed apache and mautic under root. Now some right problemes come and in the mautic forum was the advice, to let the mautic run under a normal user.
Mautic is here installed: /var/www/html/mautic/
And i have a subdomain for it to access it.
So what do i have to do, that Mautic and Apache2 runs under my normal User (not under root)?

By default, the apache2 webserver is started as root, (so it's allowed to listen on TCP ports 80 and 443), then apache2 switches to the unprivileged user specified in the configuration file. This unprivileged user, usually apache, MUST exist.

Generally (using apache as the user):

Change apache.conf to the user and group you want
You can use sudo grep -Enr "^User |^Group " /etc/apache2/  to find all references for User and Group. Use an editor to change those.

Change the owner and group to that user sudo chown -R apache:apache /var/www/html/* assuming you used /var/www/html/

restart apache sudo systemctl restart apache2.


and ps aux | grep apache2  will show a working apache2 with the new user.

In my install it's apache2.conf and the user and group are set in envvars. But maybe mine is old.
